# Items duplicate onpageshow

Tags: jquery

I have to make the page search for variables in local storage and create buttons accordingly. The first time the page loads it loads with no error, but as soon as I hit the anchor button directing to that page it creates duplicate content.

```
$('#currentSamplePage').on('pageshow',function(){
    var station = 0;
    for(i=0;i<ls.length;i++){
        if(ls.key(i).match(stationSetContainerRegex)){
            var query = ls.key(i);
            var data = query.split('&');
            if(data[0] !== station){
            station = data[0];
            $('#currentSamples').append(createButton(data[0],'#multiSet',data[0]));
            console.log(station);
            }else{}


        }
    }

});
```

But all I want is to see the content up-to-date everytime I acces this page.
[image: The first time I access the page]
[image: The second time I acces the page and will repeat to the Nth time I access the page.]
This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ch32k0/2g48V/) can help you see it, but for some reason my localStorage is not working. Comments let you know what's the input data in the local storage.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `pageshow` will fire after every transition animation - in this case, scroll to anchor. Won't `$('#currentSamples').html("").append` solve your problem though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach was as Chris Hardie suggested delete all buttons and make them again.

```
$('#currentButton').click(function(e){
        $('#currentSamples').empty();
        var station = 0;
        for(i=0;i<ls.length;i++){
            if(ls.key(i).match(stationSetContainerRegex)){
                var query = ls.key(i);
                var data = query.split('&');
                if(data[0] !== station){
                station = data[0];
                $('#currentSamples').append(createButton(data[0].substring(1),'#multiSet',"getJsonFromLocalStorage('"+query+"')",data[0]));console.log(station);
                }else if(!ls.key(i).match(stationSetContainerRegex)){$('#currentSamples').append('<span> There are no samples </span>')}


            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps, and CREDITS TO: Chris Hardie for the idea

Answer (score 1):

`pageshow` is raised every time the page is shown, you want to bind to `pageinit`, which is raised only the first time the page is initialized:

```
$('#currentSamplePage').on('pageinit',function(){
```

ref: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/

Comment: But if I do it this way the page it's not refreshed after new content is created in localStorage

Comment: Then you should use the 'pageshow' event, check your localStorage values, and if they have changed, you should delete your existing buttons and create new ones.

Comment: That's actually what I'm trying to do now, Thanks.

Comment: Where are you deleting your existing buttons?

Comment: I did it with `$('#currentSamplePage').on('pageinit',funtion(){$('#currentSamples').empty()...//Create button after empty()..});`

Comment: @falgranado you should post that as an answer to your question.